# Rails interactor : how can I have flash messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, flash-message

I am struggling with a little feature in the Interactor gem (from our friends at Collective idea).

What I want to do is to have a flash message in my interactor, just as what I would have in my controller.

Here is my create method in my controller, where I instantiate my interactor :

```
def create
    buy_credits = BuyCredit.new(send_transactions_params)
    buy_credits.perform

    redirect_to profile_path
end
```

And here is the build of my interactor :

```
def build_transaction

    if context[:transaction][:recipient_id].nil? && context[:transaction][:recipient_type].nil?

      @transaction = user.transactions.build(context[:transaction])
      # flash[:success] = I18n.t('.bought_credits_for_client', recipient: user)

    elsif context[:transaction][:recipient_id].present? && context[:transaction][:recipient_type] == Organisation.name

      current_organisation = user.organisations.find(context[:transaction][:recipient_id])
      @transaction = current_organisation.transactions.build(context[:transaction])
      # flash[:success] = I18n.t('.bought_credits_for_organisation', recipient: current_organisation)

    else
      # flash[:error] = I18n.t('.cant_buy_credits')
    end

  end
```

You can see the flash message type I would like to have, they are the commented lines.

Of course, I could have something like

```
if interactor.success?
    redirect_to profile_path
else
```

in my controller, but as you can see in my commented lines, I have two "types" of success...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to another colleague help, we managed to have a workaround this : we just pass the flash object (instantiated in the controller) to the context, which the Interactor receive. So the interactor add its messages to the object, which is available afterwards in the controller.

Here is my context construction :

```
def send_transactions_params
    params_to_send = {
        transaction: transaction_params,
        buyer: current_user,
        flash: flash
    }
    params_to_send
end
```